# JUnit testing method with assertions

Tags: testing, junit, assertions

The isSorted() instance method in class A has a bug:

```
public class A {
private int[] a;
public A(int[] a) { this.a = a; }

/** Return true if this A object contains an array sorted
* in nondecreasing order; else false. */

  public boolean isSorted() {
    for(int i=1; i<a.length-1; i++) {
    if(a[i] < a[i-1]) return false;
    }
  return true;
  }
}
```

Write a JUnit test method testIsSorted() which will fail because of this bug, but will pass when the bug is fixed.
(Assume that there is no setUp() method defined.)
This is the answer:

```
public void testIsSorted() {
int[] array = {2, 1};
A haha = new A(array);
assertFalse(haha.isSorted);
}
```

first of all where is the bug, i cannot seem to located it.
Secondly shoudn't it be assertTrue(haha.isSorted)
because when its assertFalse it will pass because the array is in descending order, therefore the isSorted will return false and assertFalse(false) will return true where-as assertTrue(false) will return false.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is on the line

```
for(int i=1; i<a.length-1; i++) {
```

Since array indexes start at 0, the definition of `i` should be `int i=0`, not `1`. The index `1` points to the second element of the array.

The `assertFalse` statement checks that the `isSorted()` method returns `false` for the given array `{2,1}`. The `isSorted()` method checks that no entry is less than the previous one (conversely, each entry is greater than or equal to the previous one). In the example, it will return `false`, because `2` at index `0` is greater than `1` at index `1`. Therefore, the `assertFalse` is the correct assertion for the case.

You could also test like this (note the reversed order of `array`).

```
public void testIsSorted() {
    int[] array = {1, 2};
    A haha = new A(array);
    assertTrue(haha.isSorted());
}
```

Comment: i see, but what about the assertFalse part?